# Fast Api Rq job vs Normal Api call

Tags: python, fastapi, rq

I am new to python Rq and I am trying to understand his usage in FastApi. Why it would be better to use a Rq job instead a normal api call?

In other words, why it would be better to do:

```
@app.post('/')
def my_method(function_args):
    my_queue.enqueue(queue_name, function, *function_args)
```

instead of:

```
@app.post('/')
def my_method(function_args):
    function(function_args)
```

Comment: `function(function_args)` will get executed immediately, and the `function` in `my_queue` will be executed based on your program design.

Comment: if `function` runs long time then normal call blocks `API` and it can't send any information to user (ie. progress status). When you use `queue` then it runs `functions` as separated process and `API` may send information to user at the same time.